# In how many zeros does the number 130 choose 70 end?

Tags: combinatorics, decimal-expansion

I have a general idea to solve the problem, which is to pair up 2s and 5s in the numerator and denominator, cancel those that are common, and the remaining pairs of 2s and 5s are the number of 0s left. Since 130 choose 70 is so large, how do I do this?

Comment: @Moo Obviously this question can be computed, but is there a faster way?

Comment: @Moo You make me wish I could downvote comments. Clearly OP is looking for an analytic solution.

Comment: @Moo How about no computers allowed?

Comment: The number of zeros at the end of $n!$ is $$\left\lfloor\frac n5\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac n{5^2}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac n{5^3}\right\rfloor+\cdots.$$

Comment: @bof Could you demonstrate why that is?

Comment: 5s are the bottleneck; there will always be at least as many 2s as 5s in the prime factorization of $n!.$ Collecting the factors of $5$ in the product $1\times2\times3\times\cdots\times n,$ every $5$th number is divisible by $5$, every $25$th has a second factor of $5$, every $125$th has a third factor of $5,$ and so on.

Comment: @bof Could you post an answer like this? And when do you stop doing the floor functions?

Comment: You can stop when you start getting zeros. As for posting an answer, the question must be a duplicate. Maybe we should look at the top "Related" question over at the right, "How many zeroes are in 100!". Haven't looked at it yet, but I'm sure they mean "how many zeroes at the right end", there is no shortcut to finding the other zeroes.

Comment: @bof actually that 100! question is different. But in [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1604179/how-many-trailing-zeroes-does-4617-contain) the questioner uses the method you just stated in the question.

Comment: No, I guessed wrong. The top "related" question is *not* about trailing zeroes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition, 
$$\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n - k)!}$$
Hence,
$$\binom{130}{70} = \frac{130!}{70!60!}$$
A number ends in zero if it is divisible by $10 = 2 \cdot 5$.  Every even number is divisible by at least one factor of $2$, so the number of zeros with which $n!$ ends is determined by the number of factors of $5$ that divide it.  We can calculate the number of factors of $5$ that divide $n!$ by using the formula 
$$\left\lfloor \frac{n}{5} \right\rfloor + \left\lfloor \frac{n}{5^2} \right\rfloor + \left\lfloor \frac{n}{5^3} \right\rfloor + \cdots$$
The first term counts the number of factors of $n!$ that are divisible by $5$; the second term counts the number of factors of $n!$ that are divisible by $5^2 = 25$; the third term counts the number of factors of $n!$ that are divisible by $5^3$; and so forth.  Consequently, the formula counts each factor of $n!$ that contributes exactly one factor of $5$ once, each factor of $n!$ that contributes exactly two factors of $5$ twice, and so forth.

The number of factors of $5$ that divide $130!$ is 
$$\left\lfloor \frac{130}{5} \right\rfloor + \left\lfloor \frac{130}{5^2} \right\rfloor + \left\lfloor \frac{130}{5^3} \right\rfloor + \cdots = 26 + 5 + 1 + 0 + 0 + \cdots = 32$$
Since 
$$\left\lfloor \frac{70}{5} \right\rfloor + \left\lfloor \frac{70}{5^2} \right\rfloor + \left\lfloor \frac{70}{5^3} \right\rfloor + \cdots = 14 + 2 + 0 + 0 + \cdots = 16$$
and 
$$\left\lfloor \frac{60}{5} \right\rfloor + \left\lfloor \frac{60}{5^2} \right\rfloor + \left\lfloor \frac{60}{5^3} \right\rfloor + \cdots = 12 + 2 + 0 + 0 + \cdots = 14$$
the denominator is divisible by $16 + 14 = 30$ factors of $5$.  Therefore, 
the quotient $\frac{130!}{70!60!}$ is divisible by $32 - 30 = 2$ factors of $5$, which suggests that $\binom{130}{70}$ ends in two zeros.

As @DavidK has pointed out in the comments, this is true provided that there are not more factors of $2$ in the denominator than there are in the numerator since each such factor would reduce a factor of $10$ in the numerator to a factor of $5$, thereby reducing the number of zeros at the end of the number.

The number of factors of $2$ that divide the numerator is $$\left\lfloor \frac{130}{2} \right\rfloor + \left\lfloor \frac{130}{2^2} \right\rfloor + \left\lfloor \frac{130}{2^3} \right\rfloor +  \left\lfloor \frac{130}{2^4} \right\rfloor + \left\lfloor \frac{130}{2^5} \right\rfloor + \left\lfloor \frac{130}{2^6} \right\rfloor + \left\lfloor \frac{130}{2^7} \right\rfloor + \cdots\\ = 65 + 32 + 16 + 8 + 4 + 2 + 1 + 0 + 0 + \cdots = 128$$
The number of factors of $2$ that divide $70!$ is 
$$\left\lfloor \frac{70}{2} \right\rfloor + \left\lfloor \frac{70}{2^2} \right\rfloor + \left\lfloor \frac{70}{2^3} \right\rfloor +  \left\lfloor \frac{70}{2^4} \right\rfloor + \left\lfloor \frac{70}{2^5} \right\rfloor + \left\lfloor \frac{70}{2^6} \right\rfloor + \left\lfloor \frac{130}{2^7} \right\rfloor + \cdots\\ = 35 + 17 + 8 + 4 + 2 + 1 + 0 + 0 + \cdots = 67$$
and the number of factors of $2$ that divide $60!$ is 
$$\left\lfloor \frac{60}{2} \right\rfloor + \left\lfloor \frac{60}{2^2} \right\rfloor + \left\lfloor \frac{60}{2^3} \right\rfloor +  \left\lfloor \frac{60}{2^4} \right\rfloor + \left\lfloor \frac{60}{2^5} \right\rfloor + \left\lfloor \frac{60}{2^6} \right\rfloor + \left\lfloor \frac{60}{2^7} \right\rfloor + \cdots\\ = 30 + 15 + 7 + 3 + 1 + 0 + 0 + 0 + \cdots = 56$$
Thus, there are $67 + 56 = 123$ factors of $2$ in the denominator.  Since there are fewer factors of $2$ in the denominator than the numerator, the number of zeros at the end of $\binom{130}{70}$ is, in fact, $2$.

Comment: You may be surprised at how small the answer turns out to be.

Comment: You will need to check factors of 2 as well as 5 if you use this method. For example, consider $\binom{125}{64}.$ There are 31 trailing zeros in $125!,$ 14 in $64!,$ and 14 in $61!.$ Subtracting numbers of zeros, $31-14-14 = 3,$ but in fact $\binom{125}{64}$ has no trailing zeros at all; it is divisible by 125 but not by 2.

Comment: @DavidK  That is a good point.  I have edited my answer to take your comments into account.

Answer (score 1):

[Kummer's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kummer%27s_theorem)
states that the power of a prime $p$ dividing a binomial coefficient
$\binom nk$ is the number of carries needed when adding $k$ to $n-k$ in
base $p$ notation.

Here $k=70$ and $n-k=60$. In base $2$, $k=(1000110)_2$ and $n-k=(111100)_2$. So $\binom{130}{70}$ is exactly divisible by $2^5$.
In base $5$, $k=(240)_5$ and $n-k=(220)_5$.
So $\binom{130}{70}$ is exactly divisible by $5^2$.
Therefore, $\binom{130}{70}$ ends in two zeros.